# Is a extension of a premeasure preserves outer-measure generated by the premeasure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I have proved the follow:

> Let $X$ be a set.
>
> Let $S$ be a semi-ring of subsets of $X$.
>
> Let $\mu$ be a premeasure on $S$.
>
> Let $\overline{\mu}$ be a premeasure on a ring generated by $S$ which extends $\mu$.
>
> Then the outer measures induced by each are identical.

So a natural question arose here:

> *Question*
>
> Let $X$ be a set
>
> Let $R$ be a ring of subsets of $X$.
>
> Let $\mu$ be a premeasure on $R$.
>
> Let $\Sigma$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $R$.
>
> Let $\overline{\mu}$ be a measure on $\Sigma$ which extends $\mu$
>
> Are the outer measures induced by each the same? If not, is it true when $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite?

I guess this is not true since $\Sigma$ cannot be reached by $R_{\sigma \delta ...}$ (countable times), but i cannot think of a counterexample